# Why does my POST call return a 404 when it accepts a String instead of an array?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, webserver

I've got this POST call in my server side which at the moment just logs what is sent and returns a status code. However, when I change `public HttpResponseMessage PostTaggedText(String[] issueArray)` to `public HttpResponseMessage PostTaggedText(String issueArray)` it returns a 404?

All my GET requests work completely fine - why does it not like this one?

Here's the whole method:

```
[HttpPost,ActionName("posttaggedtext")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostTaggedText(String[] issueArray)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(issueArray);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

And here's the jquery script that calls this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function () {
    var array = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        array.push(this.id);
    }).get();

    $.post("http://localhost:48527/api/webapp/posttaggedtext", data=array, function (response) {
        alert(data);
        alert(response);
    });
})
```

Comment: Is this Web Api or MVC?

Comment: Web API, but this is a controller class

Comment: what if you try `PostTaggedText([FromBody]String issueArray)`? Also, we're assuming you've changed your call to have only one string parameter, obviously

Comment: when you POST with an array, it's looking for an action with an array as a parameter - if you change the action to take a string as it's only param, of course it will return a 404 - it can't find an action with an array as a param....

Comment: @Alex I tried calling it with data=array.toString() but I'm still getting a 404?

Comment: What's this : `data=array` ? it should be `{issueArray:array}`

Comment: Is the name of your controller WebAppController? I have a feeling the path you request is incorrect. I tried your locally and it worked fine for me